# some files are being reset in a docker

Tags: docker

We have installed Ephesoft on a docker.

One file (in particular

```
dcma-batch.properties
```

in

```
Ephesoft/Application/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/dcma-batch/
```

is reset after the docker exits and it is relaunched. Is there any way of stopping this?

Answer (score 1):

If you restart a docker container, all data is lost, and it is reset to the initial image.

If you want persistent storage, look into docker volumes here: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/